# Os votos para a eleição de moderador são secretos?

Tags: suporte, eleição

Creio que seja uma pergunta simples para uma resposta simples. Muitos outros também devem estar curiosos sobre isso, não me lembro de ter lido nada sobre isso.

Então, quem pode ver quem são os usuários que votaram a favor ou contra os candidatos na eleição?

Serão divulgados publicamente depois da eleição?

Existe algo sobre isso que não peguntei mas deveria saber para fim de conhecimento?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Os votos são secretos, tanto durante a fase das primárias como da última fase da eleição.

Durante as primárias a contabilização dos votos é atualizada e mostrada em tempo real. Durante a eleição essa informação é disponibilizada apenas ao final da etapa.

Em todo o caso, apenas a totalização é divulgada e nunca o voto de cada indivíduo.

A [página da eleição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=election) tem uma nota explicativo que fala exatamente sobre isso:

> Seus votos são sempre confidenciais; apenas resultados agregados serão publicados.